# How to implement this cool popup div effect using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When you click the icon on the page http://www.mansory.com/en/dealers you will find a div pops up displaying some information. I just cannot figure it out how they did the effect using css/jQuery things. What is the mechanism of the effect?

Comment: They used mechanism in which they default make the popup ul `display:none` and when you click on any link using jquery it  add any class say `hovering` and add css for that class is `li.hovering li.innermost`

Comment: [Fire a reveal modal](http://www.zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin).

Comment: start by looking in browser console at the element css when it is shown and when hidden...will give you a lot of the clues right there. Can often see the live animation css changes also... at least in Firebug you can

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This mechanism is called animation. They simply show/hide the div and continuously change the position of the popup.

See more at http://api.jquery.com/animate/

I make a simple demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AZfvk/2/)

HTML:

```
<div class='container'>
    <button id="btnShow">Show</button>
    <div class='menu' style='display: none'>
        <button id="btnHide">Close</button><br/>
        Ernst-Heinkel-Strasse 7,<br/>
        DE-71394 Kernen i.R. Germany<br/>
        Contact <br/>
        Telefon: 07151 / 994 64 -0<br/>
        Fax: 07151 / 994 64 -22<br/>
        www.herceg.com <br/>
        email: info@herceg.com <br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btnShow').click(function(){
        $('.menu').show().css("top", "400px").animate({top: 50}, 200);
    });

    $('#btnHide').click(function(){
        $('.menu').hide();
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    with: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.menu {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: #fff;
    left: 180px
}
```

Comment: what does {top: 50} mean here? You set the top property 400px, then what's for the {top: 50}?

Comment: ah, it means the Top will change from 400 to 50 in 200 miliseconds

Answer (score 0):

They simply show/hide a div and position it absolutely over top the page. Take a look at the div with the id `infobox` and you'll see all the css needed to do this. Inside of `infobox` is all the text for the different countries already, each one surrounded by a div with the property `display:none`. Depending on what country you click on they will change the display property to `block` on the corresponding div and `display:none` on all the rest.